# Collection view cell animated tvOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I am trying to animate a collection view cell, this is my code so far

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator{

    UICollectionViewCell *nextFocusedCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"VideoCell" forIndexPath:context.nextFocusedIndexPath];
    UICollectionViewCell *previousFocusedCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"VideoCell" forIndexPath:context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath];
    if (context.nextFocusedView) {
        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
            [nextFocusedCell setFrame: CGRectMake(3, 14, 300, 300)];
        } completion:^{
            // completion
        }];
    } else if (context.previouslyFocusedView) {
        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
            [previousFocusedCell setFrame: CGRectMake(3, 14, 100, 100)];
        } completion:^{
            // completion
        }];
    }
```

But my code is not working. I've read the documentation and it says to implement something like
      if (self == contextFocusedView)...... but it has a warning saying that incompatible pointer View Controller to UIView. Could someone please tell me whats wrong with my code & how to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you should have an `else if` but rather just `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out. I had a UIImage in my collectionView. One of the properties of a UIImage for tvOS is adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused. So if you set this in your viewDidLoad like :

```
    _imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = Yes;
```

Alternatively, check the "Adjusts image when focused" box  in your storyboard. this will focus the image. I have not tried it for labels. or any other elements that you can add in a collection View cell, but I'm sure there is something similar.

Happy programming guys! (:

Comment: What if there is not image contain by cell?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla what I did was programmatically increase and decrease the size of the views. similar to the answer below

Comment: Yes i got your answer but what if there is not image in cell. How can it work as i don't have any IBoutlet of uimageview

Answer (score 4):

`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` will not return the current but a new view. 
Try using `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

But why not using:

```
if (context.nextFocusedView) {
    [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
        context.nextFocusedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
    } completion:nil];
}
if (context.previouslyFocusedView) {
    [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
        context.previouslyFocusedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! Thanks! :) This will scale the whole cell including labels instead of only showing the effect on an imageview and leave the other objects unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0 version of hanneski's answer:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if (context.nextFocusedView != nil) {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({() -> Void in
            context.nextFocusedView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
            }, completion: { _ in })
    }
    if (context.previouslyFocusedView != nil) {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({() -> Void in
            context.previouslyFocusedView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            }, completion: { _ in })
    }
}
```

This will scale the whole cell including all labels...